# No support for titanium.database in the mobile environment

Tags: macos, titanium

I have installed titanium 3.2.1 in my mac system(10.8.3). As I am new to titanium, I tried creating the sample app given in the tutorial (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App). When i run the application in mobile web preview, i got this error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2S8D.png). Could anyone please help me in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. What i did was downgraded the Titanium SDK and installed appropriate IOS, Android SDK versions. It worked!!!

Answer (score 3):

Titanium does not support local database for webView so there is no thing that you can do to get out of this

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-install

Thanks